# Implementing a map using doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a map using a template-doubly linked list.

I am trying to write a get function:

```
valueType get (keyType key, bool & success) const;
```

- Returns the value associated with the given key.
- If the key existed in the map, success should be set to true.
- If the key has no association, it should set success to false.

The get function will be used for the user to access the map, and for the `add()` and `remove()` functions that want to check whether or not there is an association between the given key and a value.

I am confused about what I return if the value does not exist? Because, this function returns type `valueType`

Comment: You can return a default constructed `valueType`.

Comment: I would do this the other way round, return bool on success: `bool get(const keyType& key, valueType& value) const;`.

Comment: Would I not need to return the value type if I find the value? @ Galik

Comment: @jxh Can you explain further? I am just beginning to be taught templates

Comment: If you find the value, just set the parameter to it and return `true`. Otherwise just return `false`.

Comment: `if (! found) { success = false; return valueType(); }`

Answer (score 3):

I would do this the other way round like this (part pseudo code):

```
bool get(const keyType& key, valueType& value) const
{
    // search for value
    if(/*value found*/)
    {
        value = /*found value*/; // set parameter to found value
        return true;
    }
    return false; // leave value unchanged
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
valueType value;

if(get("key", value))
{
    // we know key was found and value was set
}
else
{
    // we know key was not found and value is unchanged
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to STL [`map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/): the  [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) looks like your `get` function, so you may implement it by inserting the key into the map if the it's not existing. This way, the value of the key is the default value of the values type (such as `0` for `int`, `""` for `string`).

**EDIT:** Sorry for my mistake, I guess your `get` function is the equivalent of the `map::find` method, and not the `operator[]`. You can return a position of the key in the map if it exist; otherwise, just return an invalid position.